# batch file to swap out info between two files

Tags: batch-file

I need help with a batch file to do the (I suppose simple) task of reading info from a master file between two "tags" and overwriting current info in other file with the info from this master file.

Here is my situation as a simple example:
I have a file called "template.htmltplt" that is my master file if you will. Then I have a bunch of other ".html" files.

I would like the batch file to:

1. Go through all the html files
2. Delete all the lines between `<!--Stuff-Start-->` and `<!--Stuff-End-->`
3. Copy the content between the `<!--Stuff-Start-->` and `<!--Stuff-End-->` tags in the template.htmltplt into their correct place in the other html files.

Is this even possible and if so how?!

I have NO bat script knowledge so well commented code would be awesome!

Thanks in advance for those willing to help!

Regards,
Reinhardt

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL

SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "startstring=<!--Stuff-Start-->"
SET "endstring=<!--Stuff-End-->"

:: make a tempfile
:maketemp
SET "tempfile=%temp%\%random%"
IF EXIST "%tempfile%*" (GOTO maketemp) ELSE (ECHO.>"%tempfile%a")

(
SET "block="
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN ('findstr /n /r "^" q23715314.txt') DO (
 IF "%%b"=="%endstring%" SET "block="
 IF DEFINED block ECHO(%%b
 IF "%%b"=="%startstring%" SET block=Y
)
)>"%tempfile%r"

FOR /f "delims=" %%t IN ('dir /b /a-d %sourcedir%\*.html') DO (
SET "block="
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN ('findstr /n /r "^" "%sourcedir%\%%t"') DO (
 IF "%%b"=="%endstring%" SET "block="
 IF NOT DEFINED block ECHO(%%b
 IF "%%b"=="%startstring%" SET block=Y&TYPE "%tempfile%r"
)
)>"%destdir%\%%~nt.html"

del "%tempfile%*"

GOTO :EOF
```

Not hard.

I used a file named `q23715314.txt` containing this data for my testing:

```
drop <this> line
<!--Stuff-Start-->
Insert this
and this

    and even <this> line after an empty line
<!--Stuff-End-->
omit this
leave this out
```

And test .html file:

```
leave <this> line

empty line retained
<!--Stuff-Start-->
Replace this
replace this too
    and substitute for <this> line
<!--Stuff-End-->
keep this
retain this too
```

resultant new .html file:

```
leave <this> line

empty line retained
<!--Stuff-Start-->
Insert this
and this

    and even <this> line after an empty line
<!--Stuff-End-->
keep this
retain this too
```

Naturally, you'd need to set your own file and directory names, and I'd advise strongly against trying to use the same directory for the source and destination. That won't work at all. And any `.html` source line that starts with one or more colons will have those colons stripped-out - not that many `.html` lines start with colons, but it needs to be said...

How it works - block by block.

The first part would seem obvious. The directories involved are defined and the target strings, too.

Next there's a create-a-tempfile routine. Simply generate a random filename and see whether there is an existing matching filename in directory `%temp%`. Personally, I set up `temp` to be `c:\temp` but the code is designed to use the default. So, if the random-number generator chooses 18749 then the code looks for any file `18749...` in the temporary directory. If such a file exists, then choose another random number. If it doesn't create a file named `18749a` in the temporary directory. This is simply a placeholder.

Next step is to extract the required lines to a temporary file. the `(block of code)>filename` syntax directs any data `echo`ed to a new file in `filename` - which should contain the full filename of a valid file in the temporay directory; for example `c:\temp\18749r`.

The code within the block first sets `block` to empty, then reads the file `q23715314.txt` line-by-line, numbering each line by prefixing it with `number:`. This ensures that empty lines are processed as `13:`, otherwise they'd be skipped. The `q23715314.txt` isn't significant - it can be any file containing the required template data. I simply use `qSOquestionnumber.extension` in order that I can keep the data in files related to the batch file I write (called `qSOquestionnumber.bat`) - so the many questions using `file1` and `file2` can be easily individually retrieved in the case of a problem. The temporary file could be any valid filename you like, if you want to have a fixed filename. Note however that filenames containing spaces and some other symbols will need to be `"quoted"`.

Since each line is processed by the for as it it was `number:linefromfile` then using `tokens=1*delims=:` will assign the number to `%%a` and `linefromfile` to `%%b`.

The block processing simply matches the line that was read from the file to the start/end string defined. `block` was originally `"set"` to empty, so it is undefined. When the `startstring` is matched, `block` is assigned a value. I used `Y`, but any value will do.

When the `for` reads the next string from the file, it finds that `block` is now defined, so it `echo`es %%b to the file `c:\temp\18749r`. This continues until `endstring` is found, when `block` is `"set"` to empty again; hence it is undefined and there is no more `echo`ing to `c:\temp\18749r`.

The inner for of the second block is similar, but reversed. It reproduces each line from the file selected in the outer loop until the startstring is found, then `types` the contents of the tempfile and waits for the endstring when it clears `block`and hence turns onthe echoing again.

The outer loop simply reads `dir /b /a-d` for the source directory - a directory list of simply the filenames. The `"delims="` assigns the entire line to `%%t` and hence the outer loop is `for...%%t...do (innerblock)>"%destdir%\%%~nt.html"` which redirects the data `echo`ed by the inner loop to the file with the name part of `%%t` (`%%~nt`) with the destination directory specified and the extension `.html`

Finally, the tempfiles are deleted.

Comment: You should use `SET /P "=%%b" < NUL & ECHO(` instead of `ECHO(%%b` in order to correctly show Batch special characters in the html files.

Comment: @Aacini : Please elucidate. What problem does the `set/p` construct cure?

Comment: @Magoo Hello Magoo. Thank you for your prompt reply! Will it be possible to give me a line-by-line breakdown of what you did in the code please? I have played around with it, but keep getting errors mostly to do with the "temp" file being created.

Comment: @Magoo : Thank you for the breakdown, it makes a bit more sense to me now! It does however seem to be going crazy now. It's writing the whole temp file's content into the output html files. in other words: As its checking to match the `<!--Stuff-Start-->` `<!--Stuff-End-->` it dumps everything in the output html files.

Answer (score -3):

You can't do that with a batch file. Use visual basic or pearl for something like that. Closest a batch file could do to something like that is have the output from one file be used as the input for another file but that's as specific wait can get. 
Lottopix.has > prevwinum.cgi

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow but please avoid recommending other tools in an answer, without at least giving a solution in the required language.  You will see from Magoo's answer that there is indeed a batch solution.